# Django Structlog is not printing or writing log message to console or file

Tags: python, django, structlog

I have installed [django-structlog 1.4.1](https://pypi.org/project/django-structlog/) for my Django project. I have followed all the steps which has been described in that link.

In my **settings.py** file:

```
import structlog


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_structlog.middlewares.RequestMiddleware',
]

LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "json_formatter": {
            "()": structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter,
            "processor": structlog.processors.JSONRenderer(),
        },
        "plain_console": {
            "()": structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter,
            "processor": structlog.dev.ConsoleRenderer(),
        },
        "key_value": {
            "()": structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter,
            "processor": structlog.processors.KeyValueRenderer(key_order=['timestamp', 'level', 'event', 'logger']),
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "plain_console",
        },
        "json_file": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler",
            "filename": "log/json.log",
            "formatter": "json_formatter",
        },
        "flat_line_file": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler",
            "filename": "log/flat_line.log",
            "formatter": "key_value",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django_structlog": {
            "handlers": ["console", "flat_line_file", "json_file"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
        },
        "django_structlog_demo_project": {
            "handlers": ["console", "flat_line_file", "json_file"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
        },
    }
}

structlog.configure(
    processors=[
        structlog.stdlib.filter_by_level,
        structlog.processors.TimeStamper(fmt="iso"),
        structlog.stdlib.add_logger_name,
        structlog.stdlib.add_log_level,
        structlog.stdlib.PositionalArgumentsFormatter(),
        structlog.processors.StackInfoRenderer(),
        structlog.processors.format_exc_info,
        structlog.processors.UnicodeDecoder(),
        structlog.processors.ExceptionPrettyPrinter(),
        structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter.wrap_for_formatter,
    ],
    context_class=structlog.threadlocal.wrap_dict(dict),
    logger_factory=structlog.stdlib.LoggerFactory(),
    wrapper_class=structlog.stdlib.BoundLogger,
    cache_logger_on_first_use=True,
)
```

In my **views.py**:

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
import structlog
logger = structlog.get_logger(__name__)

def func(request):
    logger.debug("debug message", bar="Buz")
    logger.info("info message", bar="Buz")
    logger.warning("warning message", bar="Buz")
    logger.error("error message", bar="Buz")
    logger.critical("critical message", bar="Buz")

    return HttpResponse('success')
```

Output in **json.log**:

```
{"request_id": "7903fdfb-e99a-4360-a8f0-769696520cc9", "user_id": null, "ip": "127.0.0.1", "request": "<WSGIRequest: GET '/test'>", "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36", "event": "request_started", "timestamp": "2020-02-12T05:11:23.877111Z", "logger": "django_structlog.middlewares.request", "level": "info"}
{"request_id": "7903fdfb-e99a-4360-a8f0-769696520cc9", "user_id": null, "ip": "127.0.0.1", "code": 200, "request": "<WSGIRequest: GET '/test'>", "event": "request_finished", "timestamp": "2020-02-12T05:11:23.879736Z", "logger": "django_structlog.middlewares.request", "level": "info"}
```

Output in **flat_line.log**:

```
timestamp='2020-02-12T05:11:23.877111Z' level='info' event='request_started' logger='django_structlog.middlewares.request' request_id='7903fdfb-e99a-4360-a8f0-769696520cc9' user_id=None ip='127.0.0.1' request=<WSGIRequest: GET '/test'> user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'
timestamp='2020-02-12T05:11:23.879736Z' level='info' event='request_finished' logger='django_structlog.middlewares.request' request_id='7903fdfb-e99a-4360-a8f0-769696520cc9' user_id=None ip='127.0.0.1' code=200 request=<WSGIRequest: GET '/test'>
```

Output in **console**:

```
2020-02-12T05:11:23.877111Z [info     ] request_started                [django_structlog.middlewares.request] ip=127.0.0.1 request=<WSGIRequest: GET '/test'> request_id=7903fdfb-e99a-4360-a8f0-769696520cc9 user_agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36 user_id=None
{'request_id': '7903fdfb-e99a-4360-a8f0-769696520cc9', 'user_id': None, 'ip': '127.0.0.1', 'bar': 'Buz', 'event': 'warning message', 'timestamp': '2020-02-12T05:11:23.879035Z', 'logger': 'operational.views.core_view', 'level': 'warning'}
{'request_id': '7903fdfb-e99a-4360-a8f0-769696520cc9', 'user_id': None, 'ip': '127.0.0.1', 'bar': 'Buz', 'event': 'error message', 'timestamp': '2020-02-12T05:11:23.879292Z', 'logger': 'operational.views.core_view', 'level': 'error'}
{'request_id': '7903fdfb-e99a-4360-a8f0-769696520cc9', 'user_id': None, 'ip': '127.0.0.1', 'bar': 'Buz', 'event': 'critical message', 'timestamp': '2020-02-12T05:11:23.879468Z', 'logger': 'operational.views.core_view', 'level': 'critical'}
2020-02-12T05:11:23.879736Z [info     ] request_finished               [django_structlog.middlewares.request] code=200 ip=127.0.0.1 request=<WSGIRequest: GET '/test'> request_id=7903fdfb-e99a-4360-a8f0-769696520cc9 user_id=None
[12/Feb/2020 05:11:23] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 7
```

**My issues are:**

- 'info' and 'debug' level log message is not showing at the console.
- Any type of log message is not writing at the log files except "event='request_started'" and "event='request_finished'"

*I want same message in all of my log files and console. How can i achieve this?*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I haven't used `django-structlog` (but written `structlog` ) and this looks like `django_structlog_demo_project` is not the name of the logger of your application and hence the settings don't apply (default log level is `INFO`).

You can either fix the name or since your configurations are identical, I would suggest to delete the example logger and rename the first one to `root` which should have a global effect.

This is sadly a very common gotcha with standard library's `logging`.

Comment: I have replaced 'django_structlog_demo_project' with my app name and it worked :). Thanks @hynek

Comment: I just improved django-structlog's documentation regarding this. I added a `# Make sure to replace the following logger's name for yours`